# Changing elements of a list from a lookup table

Tags: python

I have a list like `y_train =[ 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 4 4 5 6 6 6]`. I'd like to change values of certain elements. For instance change every 1 with 0, every 3 with 1, and every 4 with 2 and so on. It is also essential that previously changed values shouldn't get overwritten. For now I'm using `for` with `enumerate`

```
 for n, i in enumerate(A):
    if i == 1:
        y_train[n] = 0
    elif i == 3:
        y_train[n] = 1
    elif i == 4:
        y_train[n] = 2
    elif i == 5:
        y_train[n] = 3
    elif i == 6:
        y_train[n] = 4
    else :
        y_train[n] = 5
```

But I need a neater pythonic way to accomplish this with a syntax like `for each element in y_train lookup [1 3 4] change with [0 1 2]`

Comment: Have you tried using a `dict`?

Comment: You seem to be doing machine learning, are you using numpy ?

Comment: Using numpy but avoiding if its possible to accomplish same goal with python core.

Comment: @colt.exe I gave you a numpy answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#mapping-types-dict). It is perfect to represent a lookup table.

```
In [1]: lookup_table = {1:0, 3:1, 4:2}                                                                                                                                            

In [2]: y_train =[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6]                                                                                                                          

In [3]: new_y_train = [lookup_table.get(x, x) for x in y_train]                                                                                                                    

In [4]: new_y_train                                                                                                                                                                
Out[4]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6]
```

Here I used the `get` method to provide the original value as a fallback value when the lookup table does not have an entry for it, but if you are confident that your lookup table is exhaustive, this might not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a lookup dictionary from the values provided. If you are looking to translate all values, as i suspect you are, you just need to get a mapping for all values available, using a dict comprehension based off of the unique items in y_train (which you can access using set)

```
y_train =[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6]
lookup = {val:i for i, val in enumerate(sorted(set(y_train)))}
#Output: {1: 0, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4}

y_train = [lookup[y] for y in y_train]
#Output: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this satisfies your condition.

```
y_train =[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4,4, 5, 6, 6, 6]
l = list(set(y_train))
y = list()
for i in y_train:
    if i in l:
        y.append(l.index(i))
    else :
        y.append(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy` you should do...

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.array([
        [1, 'a'],
        [1, 'b'],
        [1, 'c'],
        [2, 'a'],
        [2, 'b'],
        [2, 'c'],
        [3, 'a'],
        [3, 'b'],
        [3, 'c']
    ])
    print(data)
    # [['1' 'a']
    #  ['1' 'b']
    #  ['1' 'c']
    #  ['2' 'a']
    #  ['2' 'b']
    #  ['2' 'c']
    #  ['3' 'a']
    #  ['3' 'b']
    #  ['3' 'c']]

    col_to_change = data[:, 0].astype('int64')
    conditions = [
        (col_to_change == 1),
        (col_to_change == 2),
        (col_to_change == 3)
    ]
    to_ = [10, 20, 30]

    final_col = np.select(conditions, to_, default='')
    print(final_col)
    # ['10' '10' '10' '20' '20' '20' '30' '30' '30']
    data[:, 0] = final_col
    print(data)
    # [['10' 'a']
    #  ['10' 'b']
    #  ['10' 'c']
    #  ['20' 'a']
    #  ['20' 'b']
    #  ['20' 'c']
    #  ['30' 'a']
    #  ['30' 'b']
    #  ['30' 'c']]
```